# Is there anyway to put a div value inside another one

Tags: html, css

I have this code right here:

```
<div>
<div id="pos">hello</div>
<div style="border:10px solid black; width:600px; height:840px"></div>
</div>
```

so I want to know if there is a way to put the value of the div"hello" inside the second div with top property???????
I tried to position it with this code: top:200px but nothing happened.

Comment: `height:840px""` Correct this first. Also, you can simple put the div with `pos` id inside the next div. That will make what you want. Or you want the top position without nesting in the next div??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Jquery selector as
`$( "#pos" ).innerHtml` to get HTML of this div then after you can set it to another div
put class name or id to identify the another div

like 
`$( "#another_div" ).innerHTML=$( "#pos" ).innerHTML`
and after it modify the css.
`$( #another_div" ).css( "attribute","value");`

Answer (score 0):

```
.yourClass{position:absolute; top:-10px}
```

you can change the value according to your need , but in this way you are overlapping the value to another div, not putting the value in some other div,

Comment: But i recommend TGH Ans if you want to put value to another div

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the div "hello" inside the other div, set to the div "hello" the properties

```
position:absolute;top:0px
```

And then to the other set the property

```
position:relative
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div id="pos" style="position:absolute;">hello</div>
    <div style="border:10px solid black; width:600px; height:840px; position:absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

now you can move them.